# ASP.NET Core - Key storage providers between development and production

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, deployment, redis, environment

**Background information**

I have deployed an ASP.NET Core 2.2 application into production, on an Ubuntu 18.04 server using [Kestrel and an Nginx reverse proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

When I look into the logs of this application, the following warning appears:

```
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.EphemeralXmlRepository[50]
      Using an in-memory repository. Keys will not be persisted to storage.

warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[59]
      Neither user profile nor HKLM registry available. Using an ephemeral key repository. Protected data will be unavailable when application exits.

warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
      XML encryptor configured. Key {GUID} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
```

After some research, I found [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio) in the Microsoft documentation. It states that I should configure a *Key storage provider* explicitly. (Please note that I am completely new to this subject)

> If you specify an explicit key persistence location, the data
>   protection system deregisters the default key encryption at rest
>   mechanism, so keys are no longer encrypted at rest. It's recommended
>   that you additionally [specify an explicit key encryption mechanism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-encryption-at-rest?view=aspnetcore-2.2) for
>   production deployments.

That's fine by me and I think I am going to use Redis. *If you have any other advice, please let me know.*

**My questions**

- **Should I use one provider (e.g. Redis) for both development and production? This means I must open the Redis port on the production server and protect it with a password. I prefer not to do this and keep it behind the firewall.**
- Is it possible to use the [default provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/default-settings?view=aspnetcore-2.2) on development, and Redis (or any other provider) on production? I don't think that is possible though (as far as I understand)

  - Or should I check if the current environment is Production, and only then add `AddDataProtection()`?
- What are the best practices? I couldn't find a good resource that works for me.

Perhaps I missed some information in the official documentation. Any advice is welcome :-)